# Do the "Presidential Alerts" give the government full access to all phone functionality?

Tags: united-states, government, security, hacking, surveillance

John McAfee, libertarian politician and former computer programmer, [tweeted this](https://twitter.com/officialmcafee/status/1047585232831041536):

> The "Presidential alerts": they are capable of accessing the E911 chip
>   in your phones - giving them full access to your location, microphone,
>   camera and every function of your phone. This not a rant, this is from
>   me, still one of the leading cybersecurity experts. Wake up people!

Leading cybersecurity expert status aside, is any of this based in reality? Could the Presidential Alerts system give any government agency, body, or official, any level of control over cellular devices beyond sending alerts?

Comment: If he's talking about [Enhanced 911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_9-1-1)(which isn't a specific 'chip' or based on the alerts), then yes the government can get access to your location by requesting your location from your local carrier. The full specifications of the upcoming version of this system [can be found here](https://www.911.gov/pdf/National_911_Program_NG911_Standards_Identification_Analysis_2016.pdf), so are the specifications an answer to the claim or is there some implication in the claim that the government managed to sneak in extra software?

Comment: @Giter I'd assume by E911 chip, the claim means the various GPS chips, which is how wireless carriers comply with FCC location accuracy rules.

Comment: @DeNovo: I doubt he meant just GPS chips, because if he did then the real question is how manufacturers have been able to cram so much non-GPS related hardware and software into the chips without anyone noticing.

Comment: @Giter I think that the idea is that the information provided by a GPS chip could be accessed, not that the GPS chip provides access to the other functionality. But on re-reading, there is either some missed punctuation,  or the claim is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Giter to be clear, I think it's reasonable to ask who has access to the location information on a location server used by the alert system. But as far as my layman's understanding, you're right, there is no special E911 chip controlling your microphone and camera.

Comment: Kind of a meaningless claim. All apps and the os have access to that data. Whether the app and os are trustworthy when they say they don't misuse it is the question. Do you trust FEMA and your wireless carrier? Well, I trust FEMA, but not my carrier, for whatever that's worth. Lots of people near and on the conspiracy spectrum don't trust FEMA either. McAfee is one of those.

Comment: I would hazard that any statement ending with "Wake up people!" is clearly from the conspiracy-sphere and therefore not notable.

Comment: Look up the word 'snowdon'

Comment: @IMSoP https://mobile.twitter.com/thedailymash/status/453835189865549824/photo/1

Comment: @IMSoP people should attempt to find out what Snowdon actually made public domain. These kinds of discussions are a joke.. the government's can access at any moment.. pictures and sound from your location..the name of your best friend's mother and how many times you've bought bread in the last 5 days.

Comment: @Richard But does this have anything to do with the claim presented? Is there any evidence that the Presidential Alert System, or E911, enable any of this? We're not here to research every document that Snowden leaked; if you have evidence that this claim is true, based on Snowden material or anything else, post an answer. This "look it up yourself" nonsense doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Yes... Snowdon already answered this. They can and do.. tap all your Comms at will.. without need of any approval.

Comment: He named the system that already exists to do this.

Comment: My point is... Is it relevant to ask if president trump invented coca cola in 2017?. Government agencies already have these powers... And that knowledge has been public domain for nearly 10 years. Yet there is a concerted effort by various people to gaslight the public. This is most certainly the post truth age.

Comment: @Richard One last attempt: if you think there is a piece of information that Snowden leaked that is relevant to this question then *post an answer naming that information*. Repeatedly saying "you should look it up" and "he named the system" and "they can do this" is not helping anyone learn the information you claim to be keen we all know.

Comment: @IMSoP this is the comments section. My comment is that anyone who wants to... can check what Snowdon published.. where they will find that they are being monitored constantly.. and the data is collated for later searching.  I feel that your comments are't really 'about me' are they?

Comment: The EFF explains [that there is no E911 chip](https://twitter.com/EFF/status/1048596492087250945).

Comment: @Richard:  If you are such sn expert on what Edward Snowden discovered and released, then I'd think you could manage to spell his name right.   I mean, if you hold the man in so much esteem that you quote him at people, then it ought to be worth a tiny bit of effort to get his name right.

Comment: It's interesting that android keeps correcting the spelling.. my tinfoil hat is in for repair.. anyway.. I think you know who I'm talking about. I know you don't want to know what he published because of some bizarre twisted notion of patriotism.. but I really would recommend trying to find out what your government is up to..

Comment: @Richard:  As happens, I think Snowden did the right thing.

Comment: @JRE as it happens he didn't even say anything we didn't already know... Many think he just helped move the agenda along for the government. The power afforded by personal smartphones worn about the person.. and ai based data mining is biblical in its potential. I'm very surprised in fact that Christians haven't started making 666 connections yet.. anyway.. people can bury their heads if they like.  As if there's anything we can do about it.

Answer (score 14):

The presidential alerts are part of a bigger system that also includes AMBER alerts and alerts for bad weather and "other threatening emergencies". These alerts are called Wireless Emergency Alerts (WEA).

[FEMA](https://www.fema.gov/frequently-asked-questions-wireless-emergency-alerts) explains how it works:

> #### Does WEA know where I am? Is it tracking me?
>
> No. Just like emergency weather alerts you see on local TV, WEAs are broadcast from area cell towers to mobile devices in the area. Every WEA-capable phone within range receives the message, just like TV that shows the emergency weather alert. WEA, like the TV station, doesn't know exactly who is tuned in.

[The FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/wireless-emergency-alerts-wea) also says "WEA is not designed to – and does not – track the location of anyone receiving a WEA alert". [Verizon Wireless](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/wireless-emergency-alerts-faqs/) says something to the same extent.

If you're on a phone call, the message will wait until you're done (you won't get a message if you get off when the message is no longer being broadcasted), but I see no evidence this is done by the broadcaster. It seems far more likely that it's the phone itself that does this.

Comment: I was going to ask for a reference for the Presidential Alerts using that same system, but the FEMA FAQ you linked for the quote actually includes that information as well. There might be a better way to organize things to better indicate the reference for the first paragraph.

Comment: I don't think the analogy FEMA uses is accurate. I don't believe TVs report their location to a location server.  Mobile phones do. As described in [RFC6280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6280/?include_text=1), sharing of location information is restricted, but that's very different from a TV receiving a broadcast signal and not reporting location at all.

Comment: It is of course also technically a lot simpler to broadcast a message to all devices logged in to a limited number of towers than to collect gazillions of location data, process them for applicability, and unicast each of them from a central

Comment: I think it would be good to also address what the E911 system is, and how it relates (or doesn't) to these broadcasts.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sure, it would be simpler to act like a radio, but that's not how mobile phones work. Your phone *does* report its location to a location sever.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a complete answer to your questions, but I'd like to point out that the government doesn't need access to the E911 chip to locate you. Traditionally mobile phone networks were switched networks. They work by locating where you are in the world, and routing your telecoms through a microcell / macrocell transmitter.

It's been some time since i worked in telecoms, some of this might have changed now and I've forgotten some of it, but this is how it used to work.

Each cell transmitter has a fixed number of channels much like a television has. Once the channels are all in use, no further calls can be placed through that cell. Although, there may be special provisions for emergencies like police and ambulance calls.

Due to the limited number of channels each cell has and the very limited broadcasting range of a cell, it's necessary to work out your position accurately. This is done periodically by a regular update that notifies the nearest cell where you phone is. The cell sends back the information to a central database, for the mobile phone provider. They store all this information in a database called a [HLR (home location register)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switching_subsystem#Home_location_register_(HLR)). This keeps accurate information of where you are to within a few hundred meters if your phone has the battery installed.

So essentially, mobile phones always were personalized tracking devices since day one. Not necessarily because they were meant to be, but because of the way the networks functioned. So the government absolutely can find out where you are at any time, if you take your phone with you. They don't need an E911 to do this.

I should also point out that there's something now called a [VLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switching_subsystem#Visitor_location_register_(VLR)), which suppliments the [HLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switching_subsystem#Home_location_register_(HLR))'s functionality.

Description of the [Ericsson HLR](https://www.ericsson.com/ourportfolio/cloud-core/home-location-register-front-end?nav=fgb_101_147). I can't find a public description for the HLR at Nokia where i used to work.

Comment: Hey there, and welcome to Skeptics! Your answer is pretty interesting, but it would be way nicer if it had sources for us to check this in more detail. Could you add references to your text?

Comment: "Due to the limited number of channels each cell has and the very limited broadcasting range of a cell, it's necessary to work out your position accurately." It seems to me that the more salient issue is that when someone calls you, the network has to route the call to the cell tower of the cell that you're in, so the network has to know what cell you're in.

Comment: @T. Sar: I can add some references to Wikipedia on this, but obviously I can't reveal company proprietary references; even though i don't work there anymore.

Comment: @Acccumulation: yes exactly. It's not that they wanted these devices to be tracking devices, it's more than mobile phone networks evolved from landline networks which were also switched circuits. There were physical limits of the technology at the time. These days things are moving to VoIP because it works out cheaper and more standard to use TCP/IP, so maybe a lot of these issues will disappear?

Comment: @Owl I understand, but keep in mind that here in Skeptics every answer must reference reputable sources. More so, Wikipedia isn't usually accepted as a source for most cases around here, so keep that in mind.

Comment: All I can do is cite a reference to Ericsson's HLR on their website. That's not reliable either since companies B/S about their products. Books will be obsolete on the topic and unsubstantiated on the internet. News is ephemeral and wrong. What sources are valid for something like this?

Comment: It isn't necessary to work out your position _exactly_, but it _is_ necessary to determine which cell towers you can connect to, and which available cell(s) will give you the best connection. From the data acquired in this process, e.g., transmission time between cell tower and your phone, your position can be estimated. How well depends upon many criteria, including the density of cell towers in your vicinity. For example, the advertised geoanalytics component of [this product](https://www.netscout.com/product/truecall?language_content_entity=en), which I work on.